# How to intercept function call and change parameters with pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, testing, mocking, tdd, pytest

Say there's a function `download_page_html(url)` which downloads the HTML content of the page pointed by (a valid) `url`. Various functions use it `download_page_html` to do their jobs.

Now, when testing I don't want to download HTML from Wikipedia but from a localhost.

So how can I intercept the calls made by various functions to `download_page_html` and replace the url parameter's value?

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's stdlib `unittest.mock.patch` - it can be used either as a decorator, or as a context manager (i.e. with the `with` statement).

If you pass in the `new` keyword parameter, the function is pacthed to that - you just put a one-liner that calls the original function with the 
parameters you choose:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from mymodule import download_page_html as original_download_page

@patch('mymodule.download_page_html', new=lambda page: original_download_page("http://localhost/page.html"))
def test_my_test_function(...):
    ...
```

Comment: No need to complicate things by mixing `pytest` and `unittest`. If you are already using `pytest`, just use its built-in monkeypatch facility.

Comment: it is not complicting - unittest.mock is recomended and used all over pytest documents. This is just silly "revenge". Try to be objective.

Comment: Assuming with "pytest documents" you mean the pytest documentation (if not what else?), I urge you to open the [pytest documentation page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html) and search for `unittest.mock` or `from unittest` or alternatively download the [PDFdocumentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pytest/latest/pytest.pdf) and search that. I found zero results that way for using `unittest.mock`. So please support your claims with some references or explain what you consider to be "pytest documents"

Answer (score -4):

You should add an optional `dph=None` argument to your "various functions" and then in function body reassign that if necessary to the hard coded `download_page_html` function:

```
def my_various_function(url, arg2, kw1=val1, dph=None):
    if dph is None:
        dph = download_page_html
    res = dph(url)
```

If you don't think your design warrants such a change, use `pytest`'s built-in `monkeypatch`:

```
import pytest   # no need to import monkeypatch from pytest

def test_mytest(monkeypatch):
    url = 'some_url'
    def mockdlpage(url):
        return 'the_mock_data'
    monkeypatch.setattr(yourmodule, 'download_page_html', mockdlpage)
    data = download_page_html(url)
```

Comment: Unless changing the function is a necessary feature for the system, doing this is a very bad practice. You should not complicate your code just in order to be able to test it.

Comment: The inflexibility of using hard coded top-level functions is in my experience a necessary ground for chaning your design.

Comment: This approach requires to change the code for testing -- this is not what is intended to be.
MAYBE there is a proper way to use `monkeypatch` which will not require to modify the original source code.

Comment: @Anthon, just curious. In your second example, the `download_page_html` function is the original one, not the patched one from the line above?

Comment: @tudor that is correct and on purpose. The first part of the answer is by changing the original code to be tested, by indirecting through a function that "knows" how to handle the situation where you are testing (and hand in the parameter `dph`). The second part is for when you don't want to do that, in that case you use the monkeypatching provided by pytest as if you call `downloadpagehtml()` but in fact you will be calling `mockdlpage()` because of the monkeypatching